# limit the 10th column of a csv to only 255 characters

Tags: csv, sed, awk

I have a csv but I don't want the cell values to exceed 255 characters (out of 25 columns, this is only an issue for the 10th column).

How can I do this (I think this would be easiest in awk, but feel free to use sed or whatever scripting language is easiest for you)?

as an example, this:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1234567890a1234567890b1234567890c1234567890d1234567890e1234567890f1234567890g1234567890h1234567890i1234567890j1234567890k1234567890l1234567890m1234567890n1234567890o1234567890p1234567890q1234567890r1234567890s1234567890t1234567890u1234567890v1234567890w1234567890x1234567890y1234567890z1234567890,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18

would convert to this
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1234567890a1234567890b1234567890c1234567890d1234567890e1234567890f1234567890g1234567890h1234567890i1234567890j1234567890k1234567890l1234567890m1234567890n1234567890o1234567890p1234567890q1234567890r1234567890s1234567890t1234567890u1234567890v1234567890w12,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {$10=substr($10,1,255);print}'
```

Comment: Interesting to use 0 as start in substr. Something wrong here?

Comment: Some languages use 0 for the index of the first character of the string, so I avoid "changing gears" for AWK's somewhat unusual 1-indexed strings.  Perl and C strings are 0-indexed, e.g. `echo 1234 | perl -ne '{print substr($_,1,2) . "\n";}'` displays `23` yet `echo 1234 | awk '{$0=substr($0,1,2)} 1'` displays `12`; however `echo 1234 | awk '{$0=substr($0,0,2)} 1'` acts the same as `echo 1234 | perl -ne '{print substr($_,0,2) . "\n";}'`

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$10=substr($10,1,255)} 1' file
```

Comment: I like the `1` trick to print a line as is in AWK...never knew that one.

Comment: Its a very common awk idiom. It's most useful not for it's brevity but because it gives newcomers a concrete example of both awks condition/action syntax and it's default action which are 2 difficult concepts for newcomers to grasp but are essential to using awk efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/([^,]{0,255})[^,]*/\1/10' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl is not as good as awk here:

```
perl -F, -ane '$,=","; $F[9] =~ s/^.{255}\K.*//; print @F' file
```